# Questions about software and websites?

Tags: discussion, tags

So far, it seems like questions about slicing engine software are within scope. However, what about questions about web applications such as Thingiverse, Tinkercad, GrabCAD, etc.? [This](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-to-upload-my-works-to-thingiverse-without-making-my-real-name-public) makes me think that these are viable questions within the community. While they might not be related directly to the act of 3D printing, it could possibly lead more users to the site.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely! For any tool, software, or service that is an integral part of the 3D printing landscape, **questions about how to use them should be on topic here.** When folks go searching for answers about the products and services they use every day, I sure would like them find the answers on ***this*** site. As a matter of fact, these project teams often have communities of their own, so we should *encourage* them to become part of the ecosystem of *this* site.

It's a big growth area of growth for this type of Q&A.

Now there *may* be a line where service-related questions are simply too far outside the *subject* of 3D printing to be appropriate here. Stack Exchange works really well for *technical* support, as long as we're not trying outsource their entire ***customer* service** channel here. I wouldn't expect to host (for example) a question about a rate hike on another service, or a bug report or feature request. But we haven't hit that line. It is usually better to wait for actual examples of problems before trying to too many rules around this kind of thing.

So I wouldn't fret this. Until conditions dictate otherwise, the subject(s) you cited seem well-suited to this Q&A.